# Require file only if it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.8.7

Perhaps there's a better way to do this. I want to be able to load some routes dynamically. I was planning on having static routes in `routes.rb`, and custom routes in `custom_routes.rb`. Then at the bottom of `routes.rb`, I would do:

```
CustomRoutes.create if defined?(CustomRoutes)
```

In order for this to work I have to require `custom_routes.rb` only if the file exists, but how?

**custom_routes.rb**

```
class CustomRoutes
  def self.create
    MyApplication.routes.draw do
      #...more routes here
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
require 'custom_routes' if File.exists?('custom_routes.rb')
```

Although you might want to add some path information:

```
require 'custom_routes' if File.exists?(File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'custom_routes.rb'))
```

Answer (score 3):

You should simply rescue on `LoadError` exception:

```
begin
  require "some/file"
rescue LoadError
end
```

This is the most conventional way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

`require File.expand_path("../../config/custom_routes", __FILE__) if File..exists?("../../config/custom_routes.rb")`